# If analytic functions $f_n$ converge uniformly and the limit is injective, then almost all $f_n$ are injective

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to prove the following.

> Let $K \subset \Bbb C$ be a compact set, and let $f_n$ be analytic functions on $K$ that converge uniformly to a one-to-one analytic function $f$. Then for all large $n$, $f_n$ is one-to-one.

The converse of this theorem, that if $f_n$ are one-to-one then f is one-to-one (or constant), is called Hurwitz's theorem, and I am hinted that it can be adapted to this problem. It is proved by assuming $f(a)=f(b)$, defining $g_n = f_n-f_n(a) \to g=f-f(a)$ that has a zero on $b$, while non of $g_n$ has a zero on $b$. Taking a small enough disk around $b$ so that $a$ is not in it, then by the uniform convergence $|g_n-g|<|g|$ for all large $n$, so by Rouché $g, g_n$ have the same number of zeros in this disk, which is a contradiction since $g$ has a zero and $g_n$ doesn't.

I'm not sure how to change this to my case. I assume by contrary that there are $f(a_n)=f(b_n)$ for all large $n$, and so by passing twice to a subsequence we can have $a_{n_k}\to a, b_{n_k}\to b$ so $f(a)=f(b)$, but as user MikeMiller pointed in chat we might have $\lim a_{n_k}=\lim b_{n_k}$ so this does not contradict univalence of $f$.

To mimic the proof of Hurwitz, I define $g_n=f_n-f(a_n)$ that vanish on $a_n, b_n$ and assume $a_{n_k} \to a$. If $a=\lim a_{n_k} \neq \lim b_{n_k}=b$ then $f(a)=f(b)$ so we also assume $a=b$. Then we want to show that $g=f-f(a)$ has two zeros in a neighborhood of $a$ by Rouche, but $g_{n_k}$ does not have two zeros in small disks around $a$ (not even one zero).

The original text writes:
[image]

Comment: The cited statement seems to be that if $f$ is injective on $B(b,r)$ and $f_n$ converges (uniformly) on that set, then the $f_n$ will be eventually injective on $B(b,\frac r2)$ which should be easy to prove using winding number/dog-on-a-leash arguments. Generalize to $U\subset K$ with $K$ compact and $U$ open.

Comment: Inxay on the generalization. It should be the other way around as discussed in the answers, the assumptions on the $f_n$ and $f$ have to be valid on some open $U\supset K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is in general not true. Take $K=\{ x +iy \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ x\in [0,1], y\in [0,1]\} $. Take

$$ f(z)= z^2, \qquad f_n(z) = z^2-\frac{1}{n} z. $$

Clearly $f, \ f_n$ are analytic. Furthermore we have

$$ \sup_{z\in K} \vert f_n(z) - f(z) \vert = \sup_{z\in K} \frac{\vert z \vert}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} \rightarrow 0 $$

for $n\rightarrow \infty$. Note that $f$ is injective on $K$, but $f_n$ is not, as

$$ f_n(0)=0=f_n(1/n).$$

**Added:** Let $K = D(0,1)$. Let
$$ f(z)=e^{z}$$
and 
$$ f_n(z)=-\frac{2e}{n}z^n+ e^{z}.$$
We have
$$\sup_{z\in K} \vert f_n(z)-f(z)\vert = \frac{e}{n}\rightarrow 0$$
for $n\rightarrow \infty$.
All these functions are analytic. Furthermore, $f$ is injective as
$$ e^z=e^w \ \Leftrightarrow \ z -w \in 2\pi i \mathbb{Z}.$$
However, the $f_n$ are not injective.
$$ f_n'(z)=-2ez^{n-1} + e^z.$$
Note that $f_n$ maps real numbers to real numbers and
$$ f_n'(0)=1$$
and
$$ f_n'\left( 1\right)
= -2e + e = -e
<0.$$
Thus, $f_n$ is not injective even restricted to $[0, 1]$. Hence, we get a counterexample for any open disc (just translate and shrink it).

**Newly added:** Those two counterexamples show you exactly where your proof in your answer can fail. In the first one you have that $a=0$ is zero of order $2$ of $f-f(a)$ and thus by Hurwitz theorem $g_{n_k}$ has exactly two zeros in every open disc arround for sufficient large $k$. In the second counterexample the problem is that the extension will not converge uniformely on any open neighborhood of $D(0,1)$.

Hence, what you need, is that your extension needs to converge uniformely in an open neighborhood of your compact set and that $f'(a)\neq 0$.

Schiff has chosen $\Delta$ in such a way that $f$ is univalent in an open neighborhood of $\overline{\Delta}$. Thus, you are left to check that $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ also converges in an open neighboorhod of $\overline{\Delta}$.

Comment: Thanks. I can assume that the compact subset is a closed *disk*, Does that help?

Comment: ...Intuitively not, since we can apply a conformal mapping to the unit square that does not distort distances by more than a constant near 0 so it preserves the uniform limit. Now I wonder what happens if we are in an *open* disk, so I open a new post for that.

Comment: @Emolga My second counterexample also applies to the case of an open disc.

Comment: Why $$ f_n'\left( \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\right) <-e+e=0$$? we have $e^z<e$, but $2ez^{n-1}>e$ means $(\frac 23)^{(n-1)^2}>\frac 12$ which does not hold...

Comment: @Emolga I'm sorry, I forgot to erase the factor two. I'll fix it

Comment: But the derivative at $(\frac 23)^{n-1}$ still seems to be very close to 1 and not 0...  $-ez^{n-1}$ is nearly 0, and $e^z$ is nearly 1?

Comment: @Emolga I've changed to the case of  open disc. What do you actually mean by an analytic function on a compact set? Do you mean it is analytic on the (non-empty) interior and can by continuously extended to the boundary?

Comment: I even mean the stronger assumption that $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the compact set. (Anyway, I wonder what Schiff has in mind in his book's proof attached as picture in the post)

Answer (score 0):

I strangely think I solved this positively for any compact set. Can anyone spot an error?

Let $K$ be a compact set, $f_n$ converge uniformly to f on K, and $f$ is one-to-one on $K$. assume by contradiction that there is a sequence $a_{n_k} \neq b_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k}(a_{n_k})= f_{n_k}(b_{n_k})$. By passing to a subsequence we may assume $a_{n_k} \to a, b_{n_k} \to b$. Then $f(a_{n_k})=f(b_{n_k})$ so if $a \neq b$ then we are done. assume $a = b$. Note $g_{n_k}=f_{n_k}-f_{n_k}(a_{n_k})$ converges uniformly to $f-f(a)$ on $K$. By Hurwitz theorem there exists $r>0$ sufficiently small so that for every large $k$, $g_{n_k}$ has exactly one zero in the disk around $a$ of radius $r$. But for $k$ large enough $a_{n_k}, b_{n_k}$ are in this disk and are two distinct roots of $g_{n_k}$, contradiction!

Comment: This requires that the disk be inside $K$. It fails, as in the counter-examples, if $a$ is on the boundary of $K$.

Comment: I assume that the functions are analytic in a neighborhood of $K$ so I think it works?

Comment: @Emolga See my edited answer to see how you can fix your proof.

Comment: As the first example shows, $f$ needs not be injective on any neighborhood of $K$.