# If analytic $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on a closed disk and $f$ is injective, then almost all $f_n$ are injective

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'd like to know whether the following is true.

> Let $K \subset \Bbb C$ be a closed disk, and let $f_n$ be analytic functions on a neighborhood of $K$ that converge uniformly to a one-to-one analytic function $f$. Then for all large $n$, $f_n$ is one-to-one.

This is in continuation to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317836/if-analytic-functions-f-n-converge-uniformly-and-the-limit-is-injective-then), in which the question was resolved to the negative in the cases of a general compact set and of an open disk. To make things organized, this last case was moved to a separate post.

The counterexample for the open disks does not create automatically a counterexample for closed disks, since the counterexamples in the open disks containing our closed disk only create a problem of noninjectivity when approaching their boundary, and so no problem arises when restricting to the closed disk.

(My thoughts in the linked post carry over to here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true and I proved it in the linked question.